# Javascript RegExp get second and last string after /

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi guys i need a regexp code to get the second and last string after slash.
Example: a/b/c/d/e

I would need b / e as a result .

I've already made a function using split but i need regexp now which im not quite familiar with.

This is the function ive made

```
`https://jsfiddle.net/n7daq1hv/`
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Hi guy welcome to SO! It is generally considered good pratice on SO to also show your own efforts by including your own (failed) attempts to solve the problem. The way you asked sounds a bit like "Please solve my homework for me" which is not a well-perceived attitude ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var str = 'a/b/c/d/e';
var arr = str.split(/\//);
var second = arr[1];
var last = arr[arr.length - 1];
```

option 2:

```
var str = 'a/b/c/d/e';
var reg = /[^\/]+\/([^\/]+).*\/(.*)/;
var rez = reg.exec(str);
var second = rez[1];
var last   = rez[2];
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, i made a similar function like that but i need regexp.

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\/.*\/([^\/]*)
```

It asumes the strign contains more than 2 /.

Answer (score 0):

I've updated your JS at https://jsfiddle.net/sfebfrsp/1/

The key is this:

```
var myregexp = /[^\/]*\/([^\/]*)\/.*\/([^\/]*)/i;
```

and then [1] and [2] will be the two elems you are looking for.

It's good you provided that code - that made clear that we're not looking for single chars, as one could have assumed as well from the way you initially asked the question. ;-)

Comment: Thanks alot, sorry for the initial question i made tho

Comment: No problem - we're all here to learn! ;-)
BTW, speaking of learning - pls. do not forget to accept my reply as answer (when it is possible) ;-)